# How to stream continuous updates from an xml file

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

Example file:

```
<currencies><usd_gbp>0.80</usd_gbp><usd_eur>0.94<usd_eur></currencies>
```

I have an xml file http://somesite.com/curency.xml that contains currency conversion rates. The file is updated periodically. I want a stream to emit changes in real time as updates happen. How would you create an rx.js observable stream that emits updates in real time?

So far I was looking at this example but this processes the whole file at once and ends. http://schempy.com/2015/10/14/simple_async_with_rxjs/

How do I make a steram emit updates as they happen to the file? Do I need to merge the apiStream to an interval or is there some other way?

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: added some more info to question

Comment: Have not tried `rxjs5`, though comments at lines 5, 6 indicate _"This will push each matching
// xml node, row and error."_ Have you tried approach at link? You could use `EventSource` to continuously stream file, store last version of file, then check for nodes being added at newest event, dispatch custom function if new nodes added, or nodes changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the server can push notifications to subscribers of updates to the conversion rates (via websockets for instance) you are stuck with periodically polling the xml file using regular HTTP requests for changes.

```
Rx.Observable.interval(500)
  .flatMap(() => getConversionRates())
  .subscribe(conversionRate => console.log(`conversionRate: ${conversionRate}`));

function getConversionRates() {
  // implement logic to do one call to the xml file
  // and emit all conversion rates as observable emissions
  Return Rx.Observable.from([{ currency: 'usd_gbp', conversion: 0.80}]) 
}
```

If you really care about duplicate emissions of exactly the same currency+conversion then you could use `.groupBy(x => x.currency)` all your emissions combined with `.distinctUntilChanged()`